Is my understanding of the GitFlow release process valid?
We currently use the GitFlow process to manage our releases (or so I think) for a native iOS app.
Here are the steps we carried out for context:

We created a new repo with the main branch
We then branched off a develop branch from main
We then branch off several feature branches so engineers can work on features independently and then we merge them back into develop
When we are ready to do a release we create a release branch from develop, lets say release-1.0.0
This release branch builds a version of the app which is then sent to our QA engineers who test the app and share any minor fixes needed which are carried out on the release branch
Once everything looks good, we create a PR to merge release into main. Once the PR is approved, we merge release into main and tag it with v1.0.0
We then open another PR to merge release into develop and then delete the release branch.

This all seemed to work well when we had the first version as main had no code on it, however, now for the next app update, I am facing some issues in my understanding with gitflow.
Everything starts out the same with us creating a release branch off develop called release-1.1.0
Now my first question is that I notice the status of my main branch in relation to develop - it says This branch is 1 commit ahead of, 24 commits behind develop.
The 24 behind makes sense as there were 24 new commits to develop of feature branches, however, the 1 ahead is not so clear to me.
It could be because there were 2 seperate commits when merging release-1.0.0 into main and then a different one to merge release into develop - is this a normal state to be in when using GitFlow.
And now because of the main branch being in this state, when we want to merge release 1.1.0 into main, we are unable to because they are not in sync.
If we try to rebase 1.1.0 on to main, that won't work as it will overwrite the release branches with the old code on main.
We can't rebase main as this branch is protected and needs PR approvals to be merged into.
So please can someone help with answering:
1 - Is the state of the main branch possible in gitflow as I explained above ?
2 - How can we merge release into main when they are not in sync in the gitflow way ? Or rather what is correct strategy to resolve conflicts that arise when merging release into main ?

IMO the question is better suited for https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gitflow

Always make sure you know the commit graph and where on the commit graph the branch is that you are looking at. You cannot "live Git", and much less so Git Flow, if you do not know the commit graph that you are working with.
